# Is there a name for commonly accepted significance on iconography?

Tags: icons, terminology, semiotics

Just to illustrate what I mean, take a look at this image:

[image]

This is a commonly accepted sign for bathrooms. Note that there are no references to a bath or toilet, but a man and a woman shape.

Now, I'll use another man and woman shape, very similar in style, yet with some differences:
[image]

I think most people will have problems trying to define what does this icon mean. And yet I'm using same style and the shapes of a man and a woman.

So this is my question: is there a name that illustrates these concepts of ***commonly accepted significance*** and ***hard to understand significance***? I mean, something like affordance, but in terms of semiotics.

The closer I got to this is ***intuitiveness*** as found in Jakob Nielsen's Icon [*Usability for the 1995 Sun Microsystems' Website*](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/icon-usability-1995-sun-microsystems-website/) , but I'm not completely sure this word describes what I mean since IMHO this concept is not bound to *intuitiveness*, but to cultural development

*Please note I don't want to argue about the validity of this acceptance or if I need labels or anything else. Just the name (or lack of it) for these concepts*

Comment: I'm not saying something that you don't know, but from the design POV that sign is a standard signifier, and the result from the users POV is them being familiarized. Then you can say the icon has good recognizability, but I don't know if you are asking for something more specific or of the existence of a more complex term. Un/perceptible signals is a term used in The design of everyday things. "For me, the term 
signifier refers to any mark or sound, any perceivable indicator that 
communicates appropriate behavior to a person". Please comment if I get the question wrong.

Comment: *Un/perceptible signals* looks very close to what I mean, didn't know about it, thank you! I was leaning to some wording most UXers use, so if I use the concept "Perceptible Signals" everybody knows what I'm talking about. Maybe the answer is such terminology doesn't exist as a commonly used term. Either way, you could add this as an answer so I can vote it up

Comment: Ok, I improved it a bit and I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the design POV we could say these are signifiers and when they are used consisently we say they are a standard or just common, so I think it will be okay to called them standard signifiers.

Frequent and repeated use of a particular signifier  will increase the perception of **familiarity** of that signifier from users' POV.

**Un/perceptible signals** are terms used in the famous book The Design of Everyday Things from Donald Norman, an important referent in the UX community:

> Affordances define what actions are possible. Signifiers specify how 
>   people discover those possibilities: **signifiers are signs, perceptible
>   signals of what can be done.**
>
> For me, the term signifier refers to any mark or sound, any
>   **perceivable indicator** that communicates appropriate behavior to a
>   person".

So maybe we could just say **good(bad) signifiers** (good meaning effective, which does its job) or **common/standard (uncommon/non-standard) signifiers** (standard implying the highest possible rate of familiarity, thus "recognizability").

Comment: I replied my own question wit the answer I was looking for, but I wouldn't be able to find it without your help, and your answer could easily be considered as correct as well, so marking this as the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Rewobs answer, I got the clue and found the answer. Basically, I got "lost in translation" and used the significance word, which is close, yet not exact. Trying to learn on signifiers, I got to the following pages:

[Foundations of Affordances](http://www.uxbooth.com/articles/foundations-of-affordances/)

[Norman on affordances…. perceived affordances… signifiers](https://blogs.aalto.fi/stratusreader/2012/03/06/norman-on-affordances-perceived-affordances-i-mean/)

Which remind me of my semiotics classes, specifically Saussure's *significado/significante* (in my original language, which in English is *signifier/signified*, note the small difference!) and the relations between sign and symbols

So looking for that concept, the first result I got was [**Semiotics for Beginners**](http://visual-memory.co.uk/daniel/Documents/S4B/sem02.html) which actually had the exact answer and it even uses the bathroom guy as example.

> Peirce and Saussure used the term 'symbol' differently from each
>   other. Whilst nowadays most theorists would refer to language as a
>   symbolic sign system, Saussure avoided referring to linguistic signs
>   as 'symbols', since the ordinary everyday use of this term refers to
>   examples such as a pair of scales (signifying justice), and he
>   insisted that such signs are 'never wholly arbitrary. They are not
>   empty configurations'. They 'show at least a vestige of natural
>   connection' between the signifier and the signified - a link which he
>   later refers to as 'rational' (Saussure 1983, 68, 73; Saussure 1974,
>   68, 73). Whilst Saussure focused on the arbitrary nature of the
>   linguistic sign, a more obvious example of arbitrary symbolism is
>   mathematics. Mathematics does not need to refer to an external world
>   at all: its signifieds are indisputably concepts and mathematics is a
>   system of relations (Langer 1951, 28).
>
> For Peirce, a symbol is 'a sign which refers to the object that it
>   denotes by virtue of a law, usually an association of general ideas,
>   which operates to cause the symbol to be interpreted as referring to
>   that object' (Peirce 1931-58, 2.249). We interpret symbols according
>   to 'a rule' or 'a habitual connection' (ibid., 2.292, 2.297, 1.369).
>   'The symbol is connected with its object by virtue of the idea of the
>   symbol-using animal, without which no such connection would exist'
>   (ibid., 2.299). It 'is constituted a sign merely or mainly by the fact
>   that it is used and understood as such' (ibid., 2.307). It 'would lose
>   the character which renders it a sign if there were no interpretant'
>   (ibid., 2.304). A symbol is 'a conventional sign, or one depending
>   upon habit (acquired or inborn)' (ibid., 2.297). 'All words,
>   sentences, books and other conventional signs are symbols' (ibid.,
>   2.292). Peirce thus characterizes linguistic signs in terms of their conventionality in a similar way to Saussure. In a rare direct
>   reference to the arbitrariness of symbols (which he then called
>   'tokens'), he noted that they 'are, for the most part, conventional or
>   arbitrary' (ibid., 3.360). A symbol is a sign 'whose special
>   significance or fitness to represent just what it does represent lies
>   in nothing but the very fact of there being a habit, disposition, or
>   other effective general rule that it will be so interpreted. Take, for
>   example, the word "man". These three letters are not in the least like
>   a man; nor is the sound with which they are associated' (ibid.,
>   4.447). He adds elsewhere that 'a symbol... fulfills its function regardless of any similarity or analogy with its object and equally
>   regardless of any factual connection therewith' but solely because it
>   will be interpreted as a sign (ibid., 5.73; original emphasis).
>
> Turning to icons, Peirce declared that an iconic sign represents its
>   object 'mainly by its similarity' (Peirce 1931-58, 2.276). A sign is
>   an icon 'insofar as it is like that thing and used as a sign of it'
>   (ibid., 2.247). Indeed, he originally termed such modes, 'likenesses'
>   (e.g. ibid., 1.558). He added that 'every picture (however
>   conventional its method)' is an icon (ibid., 2.279). Icons have
>   qualities which 'resemble' those of the objects they represent, and
>   they 'excite analogous sensations in the mind' (ibid., 2.299; see also
>   3.362). Unlike the index, 'the icon has no dynamical connection with the object it represents' (ibid.). Just because a signifier resembles
>   that which it depicts does not necessarily make it purely iconic. The
>   philosopher Susanne Langer argues that 'the picture is essentially a
>   symbol, not a duplicate, of what it represents' (Langer 1951, 67).
>   Pictures resemble what they represent only in some respects. What we
>   tend to recognize in an image are analogous relations of parts to a
>   whole (ibid., 67-70). For Peirce, icons included 'every diagram, even
>   although there be no sensuous resemblance between it and its object,
>   but only an analogy between the relations of the parts of each'
>   (Peirce 1931-58, 2.279). 'Many diagrams resemble their objects not at
>   all in looks; it is only in respect to the relations of their parts
>   that their likeness consists' (ibid., 2.282). Even the most
>   'realistic' image is not a replica or even a copy of what is depicted.
>   We rarely mistake a representation for what it represents.
>
> Semioticians generally maintain that there are no 'pure' icons - there
>   is always an element of cultural convention involved. Peirce stated
>   that although 'any material image' (such as a painting) may be
>   perceived as looking like what it represents, it is 'largely
>   conventional in its mode of representation' (Peirce 1931-58, 2.276).
>   'We say that the portrait of a person we have not seen is convincing.
>   So far as, on the ground merely of what I see in it, I am led to form
>   an idea of the person it represents, it is an icon. But, in fact, it
>   is not a pure icon, because I am greatly influenced by knowing that it
>   is an effect, through the artist, caused by the original's
>   appearance... Besides, I know that portraits have but the slightest
>   resemblance to their originals, except in certain conventional
>   respects, and after a conventional scale of values, etc.' (ibid.,
>   2.92).
>
> Guy Cook asks whether the iconic sign on the door of a public lavatory
>   for men actually looks more like a man than like a woman. 'For a sign
>   to be truly iconic, it would have to be transparent to someone who had
>   never seen it before - and it seems unlikely that this is as much the
>   case as is sometimes supposed. We see the resemblance when we already
>   know the meaning' (Cook 1992, 70). Thus, even a 'realistic' picture is
>   symbolic as well as iconic.
>
> Iconic and indexical signs are more likely to be read as 'natural'
>   than symbolic signs when making the connection between signifier and
>   signified has become habitual. Iconic signifiers can be highly
>   evocative. Kent Grayson observes: 'Because we can see the object in
>   the sign, we are often left with a sense that the icon has brought us
>   closer to the truth than if we had instead seen an index or a symbol'
>   (Grayson 1998, 36). He adds that 'instead of drawing our attention to
>   the gaps that always exist in representation, iconic experiences
>   encourage us subconsciously to fill in these gaps and then to believe
>   that there were no gaps in the first place... This is the paradox of
>   representation: it may deceive most when we think it works best'
>   (ibid., 41).

## The final answer

In short, while not widespread in UX, the correct answer is ***signified***, although ***signifier*** could be more appropriate for people more related to technological systems than semiotics